# How I can connect with cin data to FILE and PRINT data in C++?

Tags: c++

I have some problem 
1. To connect "cin data" with File and print "cin data" again from File. 
2. I don't know how I can make a group for several accounts and manage it. 
I want to save and print this account data by a group.

I am trying to make banking system, and I want to make system that allows to create several accounts by users.
In this process, I want to connect with file in C++ and save user's account information in there so that I can bring back different account information and print out again.

How I can make "cin date" go to file and save this data and print out again from file?

It would be great if you could help me with. Thank you.

I have tried several way connecting with file and save data there, but it seems like doesn't save data in file. Therefore, I can not print out data from file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Bank {
private:
    char name[30];
    char AccNo[6];
    int Input_Mon;
    int depo;

public:
    void Create(void);
    void Info(void);

    void Bank::Create() {
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("data.txt");

        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "Please Create your New Account Number : ";
        cin >> AccNo;
        myfile << AccNo;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "Please Creat Account Name :";
        cin >> name;
        myfile << name;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "Type how much money you want to Deposite : " << endl;
        cin >> Input_Mon;
        myfile << Input_Mon;
        myfile.close();

        void Bank::Info() {
            ifstream myfile;
            myfile.open("data.txt");

            myfile >> AccNo;
            cout << "Account Number : " << AccNo << endl;
            myfile >> name;
            cout << "Name of the Depositor :" << name << endl;
            myfile >> depo;
            cout << "Amount in your Account : " << depo << endl;
        }
```

I want to print "cin date" that users typed in file, but it seems like doesn't save the data in file and print it well.
Also, I want to make systems that users can create several accounts and print all.

Comment: I don't see how this can compile. Do you get errors? If so, please provide them.

Comment: What do you mean by "cin data"? Data entered by the user?

Comment: Please narrow down your problem to a small, simple, [mcve]. Focus on one question at a time. For example, if your problem is getting data into (or out of) a file, there is no need to get the data from the user -- just hard code an example of data a user might enter. (Look at the file you created to see if it has the data you expect -- that should tell you whether to focus on sending data to the file or on getting data from the file.)

Comment: @TedLyngmo It is one part of my code. It doesn't have errors, but I don't know how I can save data entered by the user in file. and Print out from file.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, sorry about that I can not explain well by writing. Yes, "cin data" means Data entered by the users. I want some code that I can solve those problems.

Comment: "_It doesn't have errors_" - But the code you show here has errors. Make it as easy as possible to help you by providing code that we don't need to fix errors in before trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have errors because I think when I am trying to put File in "Create" function, it is not inside of int main(). When I put my "Create" code put inside int main(), it seems like work. However, I want to make file inside of function. Otherwise, I don't know how I can solve it.

Comment: The errors I'm talking about is that the code you've posted can't be compiled.

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh I see. I think because it is my first time I am using this website. Maybe I don't know well about how I can upload my code well? Do you know how I can set my code to be able to compile? Thank you and sorry about that.

Comment: Trim your code down into something small that can be compiled and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56719423/edit) this question instead. That way everyone can see it and help out.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ok thank you so much. I will try to trim it and edit again.